# How to obtain http headers in custom path parameter classes?

Tags: java, jersey

We use Jersey 1.13. Not my choice, but we cannot update to higher version just yet.

Jersey allows user created java types to consume path parameters. The example given in its documentation is something like this:

**Resource method:**

```
 @Path("paint/{color}")
 @GET
 public Response paint(@PathParam("color") ColorParam color) { ... }
```

**Custom java type for path parameter {color}**

```
public class ColorParam {
     public ColorParam(String s) {
        try {
           ... // implementation here
        } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new WebApplicationException("Something's wrong");
        }
     }
 }
```

I need to localize my response error string - "Something's wrong". For that, I need "Accept-Language" header information.
 Is there a way to obtain it inside my ColorParam class somehow?

If this were a resource class, I could have used "@Context HttpHeaders requestHeaders" injection. Can something similar be achieved in my custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:
My custom class `ColorParam` throws a custom exception, say `InvalidColorException extends WebApplicationException`. All the information necessary to build a response except for Locale is stored in this custom exception (like unlocalized error message, HTTP response code etc).
I also created an exception mapper to map `InvalidColorException` to a desired response that performs localization as it has access to request headers, namely 'Accept-Language' header:
    `public class InvalidColorExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper`

This way, creation of `ColorParam` is completely transparent to all resource classes (assume it's used in quite a few).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the request parameter class is the correct place to localize the response. This class is creating the parameter instance from the request, it does not create the response.

Check the `color` instance in `paint` and throw the `WebApplicationException`. There you can use all headers.

Comment: Yes, custom class `ColorParam` shouldn't create the response, but I see no problem if it delegates to some helper class that knows how to do it, so `ColorParam` then just throws `WebApplicationException(Response response)`. The problem is, that helper class would need to know request Locale to create a proper response. And I don't want `PaintResource` (let's assume that's the name of the resource class above) to create the response either, because I want this process to be transparent to resource classes.